# Running a docker container from Gradle

Tags: docker, gradle, containers, build.gradle

My code is depending on a mysql server docker  container and a postgresql docker container, how can I launch those containers from gradle ?
A docker run mysql and docker run poster ? What should I had to my build.gradle ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Try the gradle-docker Gradle plugin](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker), particularly the `Docker Run` configuration:

```
dockerRun {
    name 'my-container'
    image 'busybox'
    volumes 'hostvolume': '/containervolume'
    daemonize true
    env 'MYVAR1': 'MYVALUE1', 'MYVAR2': 'MYVALUE2'
    command 'sleep', '100'
}
```

Comment: I've tried it tells me my server is STOPPPED without starting it

Comment: I've found, 
dockerRun {
    name 'mysqldev'
    image 'mysql:8.0.3'
} but mysql is started and stopped immediately